# Get value of type=text which is inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the value inside a textfield. The textField is inside a `<td>` in a table. When I click the button I want the text which is inside a textfield, with the lables it works perfect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Bind Click Event to Dynamically added Elements</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#main').on("click", 'input[type="button"]', function () {
                var customerId = $(this).parent().siblings('td:eq(2)').text();
                $('#texti').text(customerId);
            });

  });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Add new list item</button>
    <p>Click the above button to dynamically add new list items. You can remove it later.</p>
    <table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td>list item 1 </td>
        <td><input type='text' name='textN' id='textN' value='asdf'/></td>
        <td>list item 3 </td>
        <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>list item 4</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='textN' id='textN' value='asdf2'/></td>
        <td>list item 6</td>
        <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>list item 7</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='textN' id='textN' value='asdf3'/></td>
        <td>list item 9</td>
        <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <a name="texti" id="texti"> x </a>
</body> 
</html>
```

It gives me a blank variable. how to fix?

Comment: id's should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing you need is to `find` input from current row and get it's value using `.val()`.

Here is solution:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/nvo66Lun/)

```
 $('#main').on("click", 'input[type="button"]', function () {
            var customerId = $(this).parent().siblings('td:eq(1)').find('input').val();
            $('#texti').text(customerId);
 });
```

Comment: you are great sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` instead of `.text()`. `.val()` is used for input values while `.text()` tries to get text between tags.